# MongoDB integrating with reactJS to publish website

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, web, web-development-server, mern

Is it possible to create website only by **mongoDB** in back end and **React** in front end without existing of web server e.g.: **Express**, **Node** etc?

**Addition: is it possible to publish website relay on json server in backend as a web server?**

Comment: You can done using serverless frameworks

Comment: serverless frameworks, such as what is it?

Comment: https://serverless.com/. For your reference